Find the transitive closure but with a twist
Situation
I have a set of set of elements V, and relations over V:

a R b: "a is related to b" (reflexive and symmetrical)
a N b: "a is not related to b" (anti-reflexive and symmetrical)
No two elements is both related and not related to each other.

I have this information represented as an object graph, (each node have two lists: one list with every node it relates to, and one list with every node it is not related to) but can switch to a different starting representation, such as an adjacency matrix or edge list.
R is (sort of) transitive (but N is not)
If a R b and b R c, then a R c, but only if it's not the case that a N c. The N relation "inhibits" the otherwise implicit relation between a and c so to speak.
The problem
I need to construct (create an explicit representation) of a relation R' that is the transitive closure of R but that respects N as described above.
I think the formal definition of R' is that e1 R' en if and only if there is a path in R from e1 to en such that

e1 R e2
...
en-1 R en

and for no 1 ≤ i, j ≤ n, it's the case that ei N ej
A first attempt
I have an algorithm that performs an exhaustive depth-first search for a path (where no two nodes are not related) between each pair of nodes in V. This is horrifically slow however. I suspect the complexity is O(|V|4) since I'm potentially looking at all possible paths between every two nodes.
I'm suspect that I should be able to improve this by using the fact that for any (N-respecting) path e1, ..., en found, ei R' ej for all 1 ≤ i, j ≤ n, but it's not clear to me if I should modify the graph, if using DFS or BFS is better or if it's even an improvement of the complexity at all.
Questions

Is there a more efficient algorithm? Or is my naive first attempt perhaps as good as it gets complexity wise?
Is this similar to any known problem? I feel like it's vaguely similar to Dijkstra's algorithm (since we're looking for "paths" among all pairs of nodes), but the fact that a path can not always be "reused" makes it completely different in a way.

Background for the curious
I have a bunch of people, and various subgroups of these people. I have partial information about the subgroups: Some of the groups are known to overlap, and some are known to not overlap. Now I need an efficient way to know if two arbitrary groups potentially overlap (i.e. if there's a chain of overlapping (but not known-to-not-overlap) groups).
(This is not homework or anything, this is a problem I'm facing at work.)

Your problem (called path avoiding forbidden pairs problem) is NP-hard. Here is a reduction from the CNF SAT problem. We construct a set of relations such that $s \mathbin{R'} t$ if and only if a satisfying assignment exists.
Variable: Each variable $i$ in the SAT instance is represented by two vertices $x_i$ and $\overline{x_i}$. Add pairs to $R$ and $N$ such that any path from $s$ to $t$ visits either $x_i$ or $\overline{x_i}$, but not both.
Clause: Each literal in a clause is represented as a vertex. Add pairs to $R$ and $N$ such that any path from $s$ to $t$ visits exactly one literal vertex for each clause.
Then, add pairs to $N$ to ensure that the vertex assignment and the literal use are consistent. For example, if $u$ is a literal vertex denoting the literal $x_i$, add $\overline{x_i} \mathbin{N} u$.
Here is a visualization of the reduction:


Very nice! Thanks for bringing the "path avoiding forbidden pairs" term to my attention. It's a shame that it's NP-hard, but at least it brings me some sort of closure and peace of mind.
